# Spree Payment methods gives errors with nitrous

Tags: github, spree, credit-card, nitrousio

Need help from someone a little more familiar with Spree and/or Nitrous than I am.

I recently moved my work on a Spree store site from my mac (which died) onto a PC through Nitrous (I obtained the files I'd committed to Github). After a slew of new errors that resulted from seed data not loading, I've worked through all of the kinks in the transition except one. I've tried to proceed through the checkout process, but none of the methods I have added seem to be working, and an option for credit cards is not available.

I went to add a few payment methods to make a sample order for another app I'm working on, and the following is a list of all payment options available:

```
Spree::BillingIntegration::Skrill::QuickCheckout
Spree::Gateway::AuthorizeNet
Spree::Gateway::AuthorizeNetCim
Spree::Gateway::BalancedGateway
Spree::Gateway::Banwire
Spree::Gateway::Beanstream
Spree::Gateway::Bogus
Spree::Gateway::BogusSimple
Spree::Gateway::BrainTreeGateway
Spree::Gateway::CardSave
Spree::Gateway::DataCash
Spree::Gateway::Eway
Spree::Gateway::Faxibra
Spree::Gateway::Linkpoint
Spree::Gateway::Maxipago
Spree::Gateway::Migs
Spree::Gateway::Moneris
Spree::Gateway::PaypalGateway
Spree::Gateway::PayflowPro
Spree::Gateway::Paymill
Spree::Gateway::PinGateway
Spree::Gateway::SagePay
Spree::Gateway::Samurai
Spree::Gateway::SecurePayAU
Spree::Gateway::StripeGateway
Spree::Gateway::UsaEpay
Spree::Gateway::Worldpay
Spree::PaymentMethod::Check
```

Clearly some seed data got through, or else no options would be available. This leads to my first question: Where is the option for credit cards that had been there before? I thought I'd misremembered and selected CardSave, but any time I put through a trial credit card, the following notification comes up at the end of checkout:

"That payment method is unsupported. Please choose another one."

I've also tried this with the Stripe checkout, and I get the same message. Furthermore, unless I add cardsave as an option for checkout, the following error message comes up instead of the payment checkout page:

```
NoMethod Error in Spree::Checkout#edit
Showing /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/spree_frontend-2.2.1/app/views/spree/checkout/_payment.html.erb where line #50 raised:

undefined method `demodulize' for nil:NilClass
```

(the offending line is listed as)

```
<%= render :partial => "spree/checkout/payment/#{method.method_type}", :locals => { :payment_method => method } %>

Trace of template inclusion: /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/spree_frontend-2.2.1/app/views/spree/checkout/edit.html.erb
```

My guess is that somehow, Spree seems to have forgotten about credit cards, and it has something to do with the recent move to a new computer (everything had been working fine on my mac), and while there are plenty of Spree extensions for various other paying types, I can't seem to find one for making credit cards work. Any ideas? Let me know any other information needed for diagnosis.